# Argparse : How to organize output and how to get str input?

Tags: python, argparse

Im new to this module, I type this code(not full because it said my question contain too much code)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-o','--option', choices=['opt1', 'opt2'],
                    help='choose opt1 or opt2')
parser.add_argument('-v','--variant', choices=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'],
                    help='choose var1 or var2 or var3')
parser.add_argument('-w','--word', type=str,
                    help='user input word')

args = parser.parse_args()
def Input_word():
    if args.word != "":
        u_word = args.word
        print("user input word : " + u_word)
    else:
        print("user not input word")
```

when I run in cmd `D:\Project\Search>py playground.py -h`, I got this output

```
usage: playground.py [-h] [-o {opt1,opt2}] [-v {var1,var2,var3}] [-w WORD]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o {opt1,opt2}, --option {opt1,opt2}
                        choose opt1 or opt2
  -v {var1,var2,var3}, --variant {var1,var2,var3}
                        choose var1 or var2 or var3
  -w WORD, --word WORD  user input word
```

how to make my code organize like this when it run?

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o, --option          choose opt1 or opt2
  -v, --variant         choose var1 or var2 or var3
  -w, --word            user input word
```

one more question, why my code cannot run? it give me error
`TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly`
when I run tried to get the string word

Comment: For your type error, could you mention what arguments you have passed?

Comment: `if args.option == 'opt1':` and `if args.variant == 'var1'` , but when I try to call `Input_word()` function, it give me that error : `TypeError`.. my input in cmd was : `--option opt1 --variant var1 --word hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `metavar` param in `add_argparse`

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-o','--option', choices=['opt1', 'opt2'], metavar='',
                    help='choose opt1 or opt2')
parser.add_argument('-v','--variant', choices=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], metavar='',
                    help='choose var1 or var2 or var3')
parser.add_argument('-w','--word', type=str, metavar='',
                    help='user input word')
#print(parser.format_help())

args = parser.parse_args()
def Input_word():
    if args.word != "":
        u_word = args.word
        print("user input word : " + u_word)
    else:
        print("user not input word")
```

The output is like this:

```
usage: test_args.py [-h] [-o] [-v] [-w]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -o , --option    choose opt1 or opt2
  -v , --variant   choose var1 or var2 or var3
  -w , --word      user input word
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#metavar

Comment: I see, thank you.. any idea how to solve function `Input_word()` not working?

Comment: becuase `u_word` is None, you can change to `print("user input word :  %s" % u_word)`

Comment: oh, but how to convert `u_word` to string? what does `%s` and `%` do?

Comment: you can search in StackOverFlow and get more detailed answers from other questions . as for why use `%s`, just take look at this .https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import argparse                                                                                      
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
   ...:  
   ...: parser.add_argument('-o','--option', choices=['opt1', 'opt2'], 
   ...:                     help='choose opt1 or opt2') 
   ...: parser.add_argument('-v','--variant', choices=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], 
   ...:                     help='choose var1 or var2 or var3') 
   ...: parser.add_argument('-w','--word', type=str, 
   ...:                     help='user input word')
```

If I test it with an empty input (like command line without strings):

```
In [6]: args = parser.parse_args([])                                                                         
In [7]: args                                                                                                 
Out[7]: Namespace(option=None, variant=None, word=None)
```

all attributes are `None`, the default value.

You can't test for `None` using:

```
In [8]: args.word                                                                                            
In [9]: args.word != ""                                                                                      
Out[9]: True
```

You need to use:

```
In [10]: args.word is not None                                                                               
Out[10]: False
In [12]: args.word is None                                                                                   
Out[12]: True
```

and you can't concatenate `None` with a string:

```
In [11]: print("testing" + None)                                                                             
----
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

With a fuller input:

```
In [14]: args = parser.parse_args('--option opt1 --variant var1 --word hello'.split())                       
In [15]: args                                                                                                
Out[15]: Namespace(option='opt1', variant='var1', word='hello')
In [16]: args.word!=""                                                                                       
Out[16]: True
In [17]: args.word is not None                                                                               
Out[17]: True
In [18]: print('test ' + args.word)                                                                          
test hello
```

and your `Input_word` runs.

```
In [21]: Input_word()                                                                                        
user input word : hello
```